# Take an object out of a MutableArray and place it in a new object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Here is my code simplified:

```
NSMutableArray* buildBlocks = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0] retain];
Block* selectedBlock = [[[Block alloc] init] retain];

// Add several blocks to "buildBlocks"

for( int i=0; i < [buildBlocks count]; i++)
{
    Block* tempBlock = [buildBlocks objectAtIndex:i];

    if( tempBlock.selected )
    {
        // Move the block to the selected block
        selectedBlock = tempBlock;

        // Take the block out of the array
        [buildBlocks removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
}

// Some code later

if( selectedBlock.selected )  // <---- Crashes here
{
     // Do stuff
}
```

I want to copy the selected block to "SelectedBlock," delete the block out of the array, then use the "SelectedBlock" later.  When I used this code I always get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I feel like the program is releasing the data in "SelectedBlock" before I want it to.  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the help everyone.  I fixed it.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE. Irrelevant for this question.

Comment: Note that unconditionally advancing (`++i` or `i++`) will cause you to skip objects if you remove any. You'll want to advance only if you don't remove an object.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> Block* selectedBlock = [[[Block alloc] init] retain];
> ```

This creates (and unnecessarily retains, since you already own it) a new Block. Why would you want to create a new one when your aim is to retrieve one that you already have?

> ```
> // Move the block to the selected block
> selectedBlock = tempBlock;
> ```

That comment doesn't make sense. Nothing is moved from one block to another; you are setting the `selectedBlock` variable to point to the block you got from the array. After that point, `selectedBlock` and `tempBlock` both point to the same block, which is the block in the array.

> ```
> // Take the block out of the array
> [buildBlocks removeObjectAtIndex:i];
> ```

The array owns all of the blocks it contains, so when you remove the block you got from the array, the array releases it. If that was the only ownership of that block, the block consequently gets deallocated. Any use of it thereafter is invalid.

Such as…

> ```
> if( selectedBlock.selected )  // <---- Crashes here
> ```

`selectedBlock` points to the block you got *and then removed* from the array. Assuming the array was the only thing owning it, it is a dead object by this point, so yes, sending it a message causes a crash.

You retained the object that you initialized `selectedBlock` with, but not the object that you replaced that object with later. Retaining that initial object did not pre-actively retain any future objects you assigned to the variable; it retained only that initial object.

There are several things you need to change:

1. Initialize `selectedBlock` to `nil`, not a pointer to a new Block.
2. Don't retain things at random. Always retain with a purpose. If you don't fully understand why retaining something is the *right* thing to do (“makes it not crash” is not, by itself, an acceptable reason), don't just throw a retain on it. Understand the memory-management rules in [the Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/) and you'll know when you need to retain, and why your `retain` in `[[[Block alloc] init] retain]` is unnecessary.
3. When you retain something, always balance it out with a `release` or `autorelease` message. A retain that you don't balance out is a leak, and leaks cause problems eventually. Under iOS, they cause what is effectively, from the user's perspective, a crash (more accurately, you use too much memory and the system kills your app).
4. When you assign the object from the array to `selectedBlock`, retain it and autorelease it before you remove it from the array. The retain makes you an owner, and the autorelease makes that temporary; being an owner, for as long as that lasts, will keep the object alive long enough for you to use it, preventing the crash.
5. Don't bother asking the selected block whether it's selected. You only assign a Block's pointer to `selectedBlock` if it's selected, so by the time you go to use `selectedBlock`, you already know that it's selected. Combined with #1 above, you can simply test whether `selectedBlock` is `nil`; if it isn't `nil`, there is a selected block, and if it is `nil`, you did not find (i.e., there is not) a selected block.
6. After you get this code working, convert it to ARC. (There's a menu item for this in the Edit/Refactor menu.) Then you don't have to retain or release or autorelease anything; most things just work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the block is being released from under you when you remove it from the array, but you've put in spurious (and unnecessary) `retains` in there so it's hard to tell what is going on without seeing the code that you are leaving out.

Normally, when I remove and object from an array and want to keep hold of it, I retain it. But you're over-retaining anyway so that *might* not be the problem, but without seeing the rest of the method, I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
NSMutableArray* buildBlocks = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0] retain];
Block* selectedBlock;

// Add several blocks to "buildBlocks"

for( int i=0; i < [buildBlocks count]; i++)
{
    Block* tempBlock = [buildBlocks objectAtIndex:i];

    if( tempBlock.selected )
    {
        // Move the block to the selected block
        selectedBlock = tempBlock;
        [selectedBlock retain];  // Retain selectedBlock here

        // Take the block out of the array
        [buildBlocks removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
}

// Some code later

if( selectedBlock.selected )  // <---- Crashes here
{
     // Do stuff
}

[selectedBlock release]; // release when done.
```

Basically, you were retaining a brand new, never used Block in line 2.  selectedBlock never got retained and when you removed it from the array, it was destroyed.  Thus selectedBlock was pointing to an old stale destroyed piece of memory causing a crash.

Comment: So, why is the questioner's code wrong, and why is this code better? (Also, what happens if the array is empty?)

Comment: normally you see `selectedBlock = [tempBlock retain];`, but the above written as two lines, just for clarity.

Comment: You should initialize selectedBlock to nil, ideally. `Block* selectedBlock = nil;`